# How to create network data from lists

Tags: python, list

My data look like this:

```
data = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        ['E', 'F', 'G'],
        ['I', 'J']]
```

I would like to transform the data to the following:

```
data = [['A', 'B'],
        ['A', 'C'],
        ['A', 'D'],
        ['B', 'C'],
        ['B', 'D'],
        ['C', 'D'],
        ['E', 'F'],
        ['E', 'G'],
        ['F', 'G'], 
        ['I', 'J']]
```

My codes are not working:

```
for item in data:
    count = len(item)    
    for i in range (0, count):
        print item[i], item[i+1]
```

These codes need improvement. Any suggestion?

Comment: seems you should use `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Why are there two `['F', 'G']`?

Comment: @KevinGuan: I think you have the same "tired eyes" syndome that I do - the first one's an `['E', 'G']`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Ah, sorry. I think I need drink some coffee.

Comment: @kevin refer to my answer a small modify to your own code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out you can use `itertool.combinations` in combination with a list comprehension to flatten the list:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [x for d in data for x in combinations(d, 2)]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), 
 ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'G'), ('I', 'J')]
```

Answer (score 4):

The main thing here is to use `itertools.combinations()` with each item of the list. See this example below

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] , 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

It's fairly easy to then combine the results into a single list using a list comprehension or `chain.from_iterable()`

```
>>> data = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
...         ['E', 'F', 'G'],
...         ['I', 'J']]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(x, 2) for x in data))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'G'), ('I', 'J')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        ['E', 'F', 'G'],
        ['I', 'J']]

result = []
for sublist in data:
    result.extend(map(list, combinations(sublist, 2)))

print result
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['E', 'G'], ['F', 'G'], ['I', 'J']]
```

Comment: You might want to `itertools.chain.from_iterable` the output from `combinations` to get exactly what OP wants

Comment: No. OP wants ONE list with all the edges, not 3 separate lists

Comment: @inspectorG4dget indeed, check it out again please  :)

Answer (score 2):

> You simply need 3 nested for loops

```
data2 = []
for item in data:
    for i in range(0, len(item)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(item)):
            data2.append([item[i],item[j]])

print data2
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], 
 ['E', 'F'], ['E', 'G'], ['F', 'G'], ['I', 'J']]
```

Comment: You mean **3** nested loops :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy sure tnx :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python one liner

```
pairs = [ [item[i], item[j]] for item in data for i in range(len(item)) for j in range(i + 1, len(item))]
```